# Entity framework with dapper in repository

Tags: entity-framework

We are using entity framework with repository/unit of work pattern. Now, we would like to use dapper along with EF. Below are few basic classes we are using:

```
 public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
 {
     void Add(TEntity entity);
     void Update(TEntity entity);
     void Delete(int id);
     TEntity GetById(int id);
     IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
 }

 public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
 {
     protected readonly DbContext _context;
     protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

     public Repository(DbContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
         _entities = context.Set<TEntity>();
     }

     public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
     {
         _entities.Add(entity);
     }

     public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
     {
         _entities.Update(entity);
     }

     public virtual void Delete(int id)
     {
         var entity =  GetById(id);
         _entities.Remove(entity);
     }

     public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
     {
         return _entities.Find(id);
     }

     public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
     {
         return _entities.ToList();
     }
 }

public interface IUnitOfWork
 {
     IEmployeeRepository Employees { get; }
     ICityRepository Cities { get; }
     int SaveChanges();
 }

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
 {
     readonly AppDbContext _context;

     IEmployeeRepository _employees;
     ICityRepository _cities;

     public UnitOfWork(AppDbContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }

     public IEmployeeRepository Employees
     {
         get
         {
             if (_employees == null)
                 _employees = new EmployeeRepository(_context);

             return _employees;
         }
     }

     public ICityRepository Cities
     {
         get
         {
             if (_cities == null)
                 _cities = new CityRepository(_context);

             return _cities;
         }
     }

     public int SaveChanges()
     {
         return _context.SaveChanges();
     }
 }


  public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
 {        
     bool CheckEmployeeExists(int employeeId, string employeeName);
 }


 public class EmployeeRepository : Repository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
     {
         public EmployeeRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
         { }
      
    
         public bool CheckEmployeeExists(int employeeId, string employeeName)
         {
             // Implement Dapper code here
         }
    
         private AppDbContext _appContext => (AppDbContext)_context;
     }
```

Now, we would like to implement few methods of EmployeeRepository like CheckEmployeeExists to use Dapper. What changes do we need to make in above code considering best coding practices so that both EF and dapper work in proper way. How to integrate Dapper here?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of EF?  And at a minimum `GetAll()` should return `IQueryable<T>` so you can filter on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for EF Core (EF6 works the same but the methods are slightly different).

Either open/close the underlying DbConnection in each method:

```
 public bool CheckEmployeeExists(int employeeId, string employeeName)
 {
    var con = context.GetDbConnection();
    con.Open();
    //use Dapper with DbConnection here
    con.Close();
 }
```

If you fail to `Close()` the connection, it will be closed by DbContext.Dispose(), so it's not critical to `Close()` and you *must not* call `Dispose()` here.

Or Open the connection in the constructor, then it will be available to any method for the lifetime of the DbContext, eg

```
 public EmployeeRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
 { 
    this.con = context.GetDbConnection();
    con.Open();
 }
```